# SPARQL query to get all Person available in DBpedia is showing only some Person data, not all

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am writing SPARQL query to get all Person available in DBpedia. My query is ->

```
 PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
 PREFIX  dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
 PREFIX  dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?resource ?name
WHERE {
    ?resource  rdf:type  dbo:Person;
               dbp:name ?name.  
    FILTER (lang(?name) = 'en')
  }
ORDER BY ASC(?name)
```

It's giving around 10000 rows,when I am taking the output as HTML/csv/spreadsheet format.
But when I am giving query to get total count

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT COUNT(*)
WHERE{
    ?resource  rdf:type  dbo:Person;
               dbp:name ?name.  
    FILTER (lang(?name) = 'en')
 }
```

It's giving -> 1783404

Can anyone suggest a solution to get all rows of Person available in DBpedia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBPedia is being smart enough here to not overload its servers with large queries, and capping matches at 10000.  Since you are ordering the results, you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to get result in sets of 10000.  For example, to get the second set of 10000 results use this:

```
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX  dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?resource ?name
WHERE {
  ?resource  rdf:type  dbo:Person;
             dbp:name ?name.  
  FILTER (lang(?name) = 'en')
}
ORDER BY ASC(?name)
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000
```

Actually, since DBPedia is limiting the results to 10000 matches, the `LIMIT` isn't really necessary.

Comment: @all that are active here: I don't know how often this was the reason for questions here, but is there any way of making something sticky? Maybe then people will find this answer easier.